# Smtp.js not working in express and embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, smtpjs

I am using node and express to serve pages rendered in embedded javascript. Wanted to include functionality of sending email through onclick() in my index.ejs file.

This is beginning of my index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en">
<head>
<meta charset=""UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/assets/index.css">
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendEmail() {
    console.log("I am at start of the sendEmail function");
  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "m**************@gmail.com",
    Password : "***********************",
    To : '2***************@gmail.com',
    From : "m***************@gmail.com",
    Subject : "Test",
    Body : "Body",
    }).then(function (message) {
          alert("mail sent successfully")
}).catch(err => console.log("Email not sent"));
}
console.log("I am at the end of the sendEmail function");
</script>
```

A little down the code I activate the function using a Submit button in a form, and it gets activated. But no email is sent. No error either.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="sendEmail()">Submit</button>
```

I checked with the smtpjs guys and they asked me to verify my sending email, which I did. I had previously setup my smtp server with them.

What am I doing wrong? How can emails be sent when button is clicked? Do I need to replace ejs with simple html?

Comment: any of the console.log's get output?

Comment: by the way `https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js` is quite poorly written - absolutely no feedback if there's an error

Comment: By the way, you do realise you're exposing your smtp credentials to anyone that visits your page?

Comment: Nothing in browser console except the two strings I display at start and end. So I know the sendEmail() works. And yes I will encrypt it later but first I want to learn how to use it.

Comment: so neither the alert in `.then` nor the console.log in `.catch` are executed?

Comment: None of them are executed

Comment: that is odd - can you see the request to `https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx` being made from the browser?

Comment: No I cant see it

Comment: how about if you add `console.log(Email.send + '')` - what does that output

Comment: This:
function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e) { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a); Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }

Comment: well, that is the right code!! how strange it's not even attempting make a request (are you sure you're looking in the right place to see such a request???)

Comment: Yes my browser console is open (using firefox) and my terminal is also open

Comment: can you move that `console.log("I am at the end of the sendEmail function");` to be inside the `sendEmail` function - currently, it is not, so you'd expect that console.log to output on page load

Comment: Yeah, now I cannot see "I am at the end of the sendEmail..." upon reload. Only when I click the button do I see it. Previously on reload I could see it

Comment: It started working. Got the alert 'mail sent successfully' and did in fact receive the email. What I did was create en eventlistener client-side and included e.preventDefault() in first line to prevent the form from submitting. The form didnt submit but email got sent.

Comment: `prevent the form from submitting` - ahh, well, that will do it - not obvious from your code that a form is even present :p

Comment: Yeah didnt think it would be relevant. Anyways thank you for your help!